# can anyone explain me this error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting this while i use Postgres.

```
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "retailers" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "stations" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_57ee36b830"
FOREIGN KEY ("retailer_id")
  REFERENCES "retailers" ("id")
/home/suyesh/Desktop/Petrohub_main/db/migrate/20160104152245_create_stations.rb:3:in `change'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "retailers" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "stations" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_57ee36b830"
FOREIGN KEY ("retailer_id")
  REFERENCES "retailers" ("id")
/home/suyesh/Desktop/Petrohub_main/db/migrate/20160104152245_create_stations.rb:3:in `change'
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "retailers" does not exist
/home/suyesh/Desktop/Petrohub_main/db/migrate/20160104152245_create_stations.rb:3:in `change'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Here are my stations and retailers model.

Retailer

```
class Retailer < User
  has_many :stations
  has_many :retailer_suppliers
  has_many :suppliers , through: :retailer_suppliers, as: :connections
end
```

Stations

```
class Station < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :retailer
  has_many :tanks
end
```

Here is my Station Migration

```
class CreateStations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :stations do |t|
      t.string :brand
      t.string :business_name
      t.string :tax_id
      t.string :phone_number
      t.string :contact_person
      t.string :cell_number
      t.string :address1
      t.string :address2
      t.string :city
      t.string :state
      t.string :zip
      t.string :station_reg_number
      t.references :retailer, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I dont have retailer migration because its inheriting from the User. Here is my User migration

User

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

Add Type to User

```
class AddTypeToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :type, :string
  end
end
```

Add extra attributes to user

```
class AddExtraToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :first_name, :string
    add_column :users, :last_name, :string
    add_column :users, :phone_number, :string
    add_column :users, :cell_number, :string
    add_column :users, :tax_id, :string
    add_column :users, :business_name, :string
    add_column :users, :address1, :string
    add_column :users, :address2, :string
    add_column :users, :city, :string
    add_column :users, :state, :string
    add_column :users, :zip_code, :string
    add_column :users, :years_in_business, :string
  end
end
```

And add account number to user

```
class AddAccountNumberToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :account_number, :string
    add_index :users, :account_number
  end
end
```

It works with no errors when i use Sqlite3 but i get errors in Production heroku using postgres. so i decided to use postgres in developemnt and i saw the above errors which i cannot understand. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "retailers" does not exist
```

This error simply means that the `retailers` table is not present in your database when you try to reference this in another place. All you need is to make sure you create `retailers` table before you try to use/reference it in some some migration.

Comment: Retailers inherit from User. SO i figured retailer table is not needed. Its just User table. so should i change the code to has_many users and such?

Comment: You can still use `retailer` but specify the class name as: `User` like such: `belongs_to :retailer, class_name: 'User'` and `has_many :retailers, class_name: 'User'`

Comment: Ahhh let me try that.

Comment: How to i do that in "through" association?

Comment: still getting same error after that. should i change the migration to use User instead of retailers and suppliers? and in association i do retailers with class user?

Comment: try that and let me know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from this line in your migration:

```
  t.references :retailer, index: true, foreign_key: true
```

The foreign key option means that rails is trying to create a foreign key between retailer_id on the stations table and id on the non existant retailers table.

Although migrations are frequently created at the same time as a model, they're not really connected - the migration doesn't know that retailer is an STI model.

As far as I can tell you will need to remove the foreign key option from the call to `references` and add the foreign separately with `add_foreign_key`:

```
add_foreign_key :stations, :users, column: "retailer_id"
```

You probably didn't encounter this in development because earlier versions  of sqlite3 didn't support foreign keys and current versions require that it be activated (see [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)): unless activated it just ignores foreign key constraints (as long as they are syntactically correct)